# Array of Arrays as Iterable of Iterables

Tags: arrays, scala, iterable

Let's consider the following definition to add up all elements in a nested Iterable structure of Ints:

```
def add(xss : Iterable[Iterable[Int]]) : Int = xss.map(_.sum).sum
```

However, evaluating following expression yields a type error:

```
   scala> add(Array(Array(1,2,3)))
   <console>:9: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Array[Array[Int]]
   required: Iterable[Iterable[Int]]
                add(Array(Array(1,2,3)))
                         ^
```

The function works as expected with other Iterables (like Lists). How can I avoid that error? What's the rationale for it? Guess that is something to do with Arrays being native from Java, but don't know the specifics details in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Is that method supposed to accept `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]` instead? Because this compiles for me.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake copying the code. Now it's been corrected. Thanks. The error persists as indicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because Scala would need to use 2 implicit conversion in a row to go from `Array[Array[Int]]` to `Iterable[Iterable[Int]]`, which it (purposefully) doesn't do.

You could specify the outer `Array`'s type :

```
scala> add(Array[Iterable[Int]](Array(1,2,3)))
res4: Int = 6
```

or transform its elements to `Iterable[Int]` (thus bypassing an implicit conversion) :

```
scala> add(Array(Array(1,2,3)).map(_.toIterable))
res5: Int = 6
```

---

The problem comes from the fact that Scala's `Array[T]` is just a representation for Java's `T[]`. What makes `Array[T]` behave like an usual Scala collection is an implicit conversion in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$).

From [`Array`'s documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) :

> Two implicit conversions exist in *scala.Predef* that are frequently
>   applied to arrays: a conversion to *mutable.ArrayOps*
>   and a conversion to *mutable.WrappedArray* (a subtype of *scala.collection.Seq*). Both types make available many of the standard
>   operations found in the Scala collections API. The conversion to
>   *ArrayOps* is temporary, as all operations defined on *ArrayOps* return an
>   *Array*, while the conversion to *WrappedArray* is permanent as all
>   operations return a *WrappedArray*.
>
> The conversion to *ArrayOps* takes priority over the conversion to
>   *WrappedArray*.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the problem with doing directly 2 implicit conversions?

Comment: @ppgllrd : I couldn't find any official reason for this, but my guess would be that it would dramatically increase the number of possible conversions and simply isn't worth it. Plus (simple) implicit conversions can already make it hard to understand a piece of code, I really don't want to have to try and understand 'nested' implicit conversions.

Comment: Thanks again. These irregularities of arrays wrt other Scala data structures is one of the things I like less about this great programming language. Price to pay for using efficient arrays from underlining JVM.

Answer (score -1):

Your intuition is correct. See the `Array` type signature:

```
final class Array[T] extends java.io.Serializable with java.lang.Cloneable
```

contrast that with `Seq` type signature:

```
trait Seq[+A] extends Iterable[A] with collection.Seq[A] ...
```

As you can see `Array` does not relate to the `Iterable[A]` trait.

You can fix this by calling `toIterable` on the instance:

```
scala> add(Array(Array(1,2,3).toIterable).toIterable)
res1: Int = 6
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin, but what intrigues me is that if I remove the nesting, Arrays can be used as Iterables. For example,  `def add2(xs : Iterable[Int]) = xs.sum` works properly with  `add2(Array(1,2,3))`.